# How can I manage and track the patches?

Tags: version-control

How can I manage and track the patches (functionality new and old) to the modules and sub-modules of my project in an Organization?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) This is a Q+A site for questions specifically about the Drupal CMS - currently it's not clear what you need, but the best I can guess is that you're asking for advice on how to manage patch files in a version control system. Managing patch files in VCS isn't really a Drupal problem - if there's something about the workflow you want to use that Drupal is stopping you from doing, and you need help getting around it, that would make a good question for this site. Currently it's too broad, ambiguous, and potentially opinion-based to answer here

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/davereid/drush-patchfile and https://www.drupal.org/project/drush_iq are both Drush specific tools to help with patch management.  While Drush is no longer a Drupal specific tool, WordPress and Backdrop use modern PRs.  Since Drupal is the only popular PHP project still using patches, questions about managing patches is already Drupal specific.

Comment: @kreynen Patching isn't a PHP concept either, I'm not sure what point you're making there.

Comment: I'm not sure why I have to explain this, but you put the issue on hold giving "...etc. that do not relate directly to Drupal are off-topic here" as the reason.  While there are certainly better ways to phrase the question, managing patches is something that IS still related directly to Drupal. I probably wouldn't have mentioned if if you had flagged it as too broad or a duplicate (http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36384/how-to-manage-version-control-for-patched-contrib-modules), but you didn't.